# How can I get a date entered in a VB6 application to display on a Crystal report?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a VB6 application where a user inputs a date range and the dates are used to populate a Crystal 8.5 report using a selection formula within the VB6 code. I need to display the date the user selected on the report. Since the date is technically not a parameter, I am not sure what I can put within the field object/formula field to get the date from the application. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to pass the date as a parameter from the VB form to the Crystal Report report file?

Comment: No, the data is getting passed from VB to report through a selection formula instead of as a parameter. I cannot change the VB code, so I have to keep it as is. This whole thing would be much easier if it were passed as a parameter, but it's not.